# What is "Invoke" and why is it taking so much time to run in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to improve the performance of my Azure Function.
Looking in Application Insights dependencies telemetry, I could see that some "Invoke" is taking a lot of time to run.

[image: End-toEnd transaction log]

Does anyone know what is this "Invoke" trace and how to improve its performance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- In your case, the ***Invoke*** in ***Internal*** type open telemetry in the ***Application Insights*** could be referring to the **invocation** of your Azure Function such as the time taken to execute a specific operation like database query, an HTTP request, or any other operation.
- As you are using SQL triggered Azure function, the trigger will invoke the function whenever any specific event occurs in your SQL database.
- In your case, the duration of the "Invoke" telemetry which is 2.5s seems to be due to the database related activities.
- Try to scale your function to multiple instances to improve the performance of your Azure Function.

To check function app's performance, query traces in the logs or check the metrics and Performance.

[image]

- I tried creating an SQL triggered Azure function, but there is no Invoke type in my logs.

**Below are the logs of my Azure function:**

[image]

**References:**

[Azure Monitor Application Insights - Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-overview?tabs=aspnetcore#opentelemetry)